# How to clear a Text Input in Powerapp?

Tags: textinput, powerapps

In Powerapp app, I have screen,which contain

1 : "text input", to enter CityName

2 : When I click on Clear button, How can I clear value of text input ?

[Click here for more details of problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9flRm.png)

**Solution**

step 1 : let text input name is "txtCity" and set it's Default property to ""

step 2 : set **OnSelect** event of button to **Reset(txtCity)**

[solution shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDnOm.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be one way of resetting, there are other ways to solve it too. By assigning a variable to TextInput's default property and setting that variable to "" or any other default value you want based on the scenario. How and when to use reset can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/sl-si/powerapps/functions/function-reset